# Wordpress execute edit_user_profile_update before user_profile_update_errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress userprofile editing.

The problem is that the validate function is executing after the update function so what i get on my wordpress is the error but the fields updated.

```
function bw_admin_validate_fields($errors, $update, $user){
    if(isset($_POST["credits"]) && !ctype_digit($_POST['credits'])){
        $errors->add("credits_error","The field credits must be a number");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['ipaddress']) && !filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = gethostbyname($_POST['ipaddress']);
        if($ip == $_POST['ipaddress'])
            $errors->add("ip_error","You must enter a valid ip address or a hostname");
    }
}
```

.

```
function bw_admin_save_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) || !ImAdmin() )
        return false;

    if(isset($_POST['generate']) && isset($_POST["ipaddress"])){
        $ip = $_POST['ipaddress'];
        if(!filter_var($ip,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = gethostbyname($_POST['ipaddress']);
        $key = API::I()->createApi($ip);
        update_user_meta($user_id,"api_key",$key);
    }
    else{
        $apikey = trim(get_user_meta($user_id,'api_key',true));
        $banned = isset($_POST['banned']) && $_POST['banned']  ? true : false;
        if($banned) API::I()->Ban($apikey);
        else API::I()->UnBan($apikey);
        if(isset($_POST['credits']) && ctype_digit($_POST['credits']))
        {
            if(((int)$_POST['credits']) < 0) $_POST['credits'] = 0;
            API::I()->setCredits($_POST['credits'],$apikey);
        }
    }
}
```

And when i hit the edit button wordpress says me that i have to enter a valid ip or valid hostname but the Api is already created.